# Should vanilla solutions be avoided in Spring web applications?

Tags: java, design, clean-code, spring

I am making a Java and Spring webapp that scrapes data from a web and then publishes it through an API. Some of the raw scrapped data is in the form of `Set<SomeObject>` which I then convert to a `Set<ConvertedObject>`. The thing is, there is a field that has a repeating value in a lot of `SomeObject` and I want to avoid converting it more than once - it isn't an expensive operation but still.

So far I have come up with two solutions:

- Extract that field from `SomeObject` to a `Map<String, Set<SomeObject>>`, which is easy to do from the web I am scrapping (like 5 lines of code).
- Keep the field inside `SomeObject` and make an internal service with cache to convert that field, which is also easy to do with Spring.

The possible values are not so many; 7 values cover 95%+ of the entities, but some times there are some other values apart from those which I am able to parse.

I like the second solution in that the code becomes cleaner, no complicated Map and Set structure, but it is also a more sophisticated one in my opinion that isn't really necessary.

Which one do you think is better?

To better clarify, I am most concerned with clean code rather than efficiency. Plus, I am also interested in a general answer regarding Spring web applications design. Should I use components everywhere I can or sometimes vanilla solutions are better?

Comment: To some extent, algorithms and data structures are used with most things especially with OOP (object-oriented programming), so it makes your question seem off topic or in need of some clarification into what you mean by "avoid". With just the main content at a glance, what are you meaning with "a field that has repeating value in a lot of SomeObject"? Is it that over each SomeObject collection item this field is typically the same value, or that the actual value held in a field is also seen held in other fields of SomeObject?

Comment: The question in the title makes no sense. Your scraper _is_ an algorithm, your classes _are_ data structures. All code is either an algorithm (function/method/operation) or data (fields/properties/variables). If you had neither, you wouldn't have built anything.

Comment: _"it isn't an expensive operation but still"_ This implies you're doing it _just because_, which sets you off on the wrong foot from the start. Solutions exist to solve problems. If you can't point out the problem, there's no point in trying to provide a solution (the only exception to this is teaching exercises - but then the question itself becomes moot)

Comment: It means this field has tipically the same value. I know the wording of the question is not the best, I accept any suggestions you can make. But I think you can get what I'm asking. In a way the question is whether you would solve this problem in a "vanilla" way or rely on more complex concepts like Spring components with cache. The operation involves parsing a string with a 10 to 20 length. It's not expensive but I will do it many times. I considered calculating it many times but then I could just do the map from solution nr 1

Comment: To better clarify, I am most concerned with getting clean code. Making a map to avoid converting the same value many times or just making a set are both my decision, it's not like making the map involves a lot of trouble for a problem that isn't there. They involve roughly the same amount of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

A cache is the correct solution. I would keep the signature of the cache the same as the conversion function. If a conversion function converts a string to a string, I would keep the cache a Map.

You'll want to pick a fixed size LRU cache so infrequently used items don't clog the cache.